# jQuery Count, count individually

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have counters in my cart and I'm struggling to get the controls to only target the specific counter I'm on. Instead, it's updating them all.

```js
// Product Counter
DecreaseCount = function(){
  var count = $(".quantity__count").val();
  if (count > 0) count--;
  if (count == 0) count = 0;
  $(".quantity__count").val(count);
}

IncreaseCount = function(){
  var count = $('.quantity__count').val();
  if (count < 99) count++;
  if (count == 99) count = 99;
  $('.quantity__count').val(count);
}

// Does both
$('.quantity__decrement').click(function(){
  DecreaseCount();
});
$('.quantity__increment').click(function(){
  IncreaseCount();
});


// What I've tried
//$('.quantity__decrement').each(function(){
//  $(this).on("click", function(){
//    debugger;
//    var count = $(".quantity__count").val();
//    if (count > 0) count--;
//    if (count == 0) count = 0;
//    $(".quantity__count").val(count);
//  }); 
//});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="o-grid o-grid--no-gutter">  
  <div class="quantity o-grid__cell">
    <div class="quantity__decrement">-</div>
    <input type="num" class="quantity__count" value="0" />
    <div class="quantity__increment">+</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="o-grid o-grid--no-gutter">
  <div class="quantity o-grid__cell">
    <div class="quantity__decrement">-</div>
    <input type="num" class="quantity__count" value="0" />
    <div class="quantity__increment">+</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using .closest, .siblings etc; I'm a bit stumped and I know this isn't a tricky thing to do.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with one function and pass clicked element and change type as parameters. Then inside that function based on change parameter you add or subtract from `count` value.

```js
ChangeCount = function(el, change) {
  var count = el.siblings(".quantity__count").val();
  change == "add" ? count++ : count--;
  if (count < 0) count = 0;
  if (count > 99) count = 99
  el.siblings(".quantity__count").val(count);
}

$('.quantity > div').click(function() {
  const change = $(this).hasClass('quantity__decrement') ? 'sub' : 'add';
  ChangeCount($(this), change)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="o-grid o-grid--no-gutter">
  <div class="quantity o-grid__cell">
    <div class="quantity__decrement">-</div>
    <input type="num" class="quantity__count" value="0">
    <div class="quantity__increment">+</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="o-grid o-grid--no-gutter">
  <div class="quantity o-grid__cell">
    <div class="quantity__decrement">-</div>
    <input type="num" class="quantity__count" value="0">
    <div class="quantity__increment">+</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `siblings` to select the `quantity__count` field and bind that element as the `this` context to provide a cleaner approach.

```js
// Product Counter
DecreaseCount = function() {
              // +--- context this with the selected element.
              // |
              // v
  var count = $(this).val();
  if (count > 0) count--;
  if (count == 0) count = 0;
  $(this).val(count);
}

IncreaseCount = function() {
              // +--- context this with the selected element.
              // |
              // v
  var count = $(this).val();
  if (count < 99) count++;
  if (count == 99) count = 99;
  $(this).val(count);
}

// Does both
$('.quantity__decrement').click(function() {
  var target = $(this).siblings('[class="quantity__count"]').get(0);
                    // +--- Bind the function with the selected element.
                    // |
                    // v
  DecreaseCount.bind(target)();
});

$('.quantity__increment').click(function() {
  var target = $(this).siblings('[class="quantity__count"]').get(0);
                    // +--- Bind the function with the selected element.
                    // |
                    // v
  IncreaseCount.bind(target)();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="o-grid o-grid--no-gutter">
  <div class="quantity o-grid__cell">
    <div class="quantity__decrement">-</div>
    <input type="num" class="quantity__count" value="0" />
    <div class="quantity__increment">+</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="o-grid o-grid--no-gutter">
  <div class="quantity o-grid__cell">
    <div class="quantity__decrement">-</div>
    <input type="num" class="quantity__count" value="0" />
    <div class="quantity__increment">+</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would bind the click event on each item:

```js
$('.quantity__decrement').each(function(){
  $(this).on('click', function(){
    var quantityCount = $(this).siblings('.quantity__count');
    var count = quantityCount.val();
    if (count > 0) count--;
    if (count == 0) count = 0;
    quantityCount.val(count);
  });
});


$('.quantity__increment').each(function(){
  $(this).on('click', function(){
    var quantityCount = $(this).siblings('.quantity__count');
    var count = quantityCount.val();
    if (count < 99 ) count++;
    if (count == 99) count = 99;
    quantityCount.val(count);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="o-grid o-grid--no-gutter">  
    <div class="quantity o-grid__cell">
      <div class="quantity__decrement">-</div>
      <input type="num" class="quantity__count" value="0" />
      <div class="quantity__increment">+</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="o-grid o-grid--no-gutter">
    <div class="quantity o-grid__cell">
      <div class="quantity__decrement">-</div>
      <input type="num" class="quantity__count" value="0" />
      <div class="quantity__increment">+</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You can also implement it, using the e.target, like this:

```js
    // Product Counter
    DecreaseCount = function(element){
      var quantityCount = $(element).siblings('.quantity__count');
      var count = quantityCount.val();
      if (count > 0) count--;
      if (count == 0) count = 0;
      quantityCount.val(count);
    }
    
    IncreaseCount = function(element){
      var quantityCount = $(element).siblings('.quantity__count');
      var count = quantityCount.val();
      if (count < 99) count++;
      if (count == 99) count = 99;
      quantityCount.val(count);
    }
    
    // Does both
    $('.quantity__decrement').click(function(e){
      DecreaseCount(e.target);
    });
    $('.quantity__increment').click(function(e){
      IncreaseCount(e.target);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="o-grid o-grid--no-gutter">  
    <div class="quantity o-grid__cell">
      <div class="quantity__decrement">-</div>
      <input type="num" class="quantity__count" value="0" />
      <div class="quantity__increment">+</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="o-grid o-grid--no-gutter">
    <div class="quantity o-grid__cell">
      <div class="quantity__decrement">-</div>
      <input type="num" class="quantity__count" value="0" />
      <div class="quantity__increment">+</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML is not going to change, you can simply use `.next()` and `.prev()` selectors.

To make it a bit more generic you could use `$(this).parent().find('.quantity__count')`.

Answer (score 1):

**Some basic use of data attibute would solve your problem.**

```js
// Product Counter
DecreaseCount = function(ID){
  var count = $("#pro"+ID).val();
  if (count > 0) count--;
  if (count == 0) count = 0;
  $("#pro"+ID).val(count);
}

IncreaseCount = function(ID){
  var count = $("#pro"+ID).val();
  if (count < 99) count++;
  if (count == 99) count = 99;
  $("#pro"+ID).val(count);
}

// Does both
$('.quantity__decrement').click(function(){
  DecreaseCount($(this).data("id"));
});
$('.quantity__increment').click(function(){
  IncreaseCount($(this).data("id"));
});


// What I've tried
//$('.quantity__decrement').each(function(){
//  $(this).on("click", function(){
//    debugger;
//    var count = $(".quantity__count").val();
//    if (count > 0) count--;
//    if (count == 0) count = 0;
//    $(".quantity__count").val(count);
//  }); 
//});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="o-grid o-grid--no-gutter">  
  <div class="quantity o-grid__cell">
    <div data-id="2" class="quantity__decrement">-</div>
    <input id="pro2" type="num" class="quantity__count" value="0" />
    <div data-id="2" class="quantity__increment">+</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="o-grid o-grid--no-gutter">
  <div class="quantity o-grid__cell">
    <div data-id="1" class="quantity__decrement">-</div>
    <input id="pro1" type="num" class="quantity__count" value="0" />
    <div data-id="1" class="quantity__increment">+</div>
  </div>
</div>
```